# Pig 0.13.0 Installation on windows 8

Tags: windows, hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I could get into the grunt shell in ***pig 0.13.0*** version on windows. When trying to load a simple file from hdfs and dump it. The following error occurs.

```
2014-10-13 17:29:45,167 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 29
98: Unhandled internal error. org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext
Details at logfile: C:\hadoop-2.5.1\logs\pig_1413201361692.log
```

Do anyone faced this error ever? I need a solution to solve this.

Comment: what is the content in C:\hadoop-2.5.1\logs\pig_1413201361692.log

Comment: Thanks sonic, 

the content was
Unexpected System Error Occured: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected

Comment: what is the version of hadoop and what is the version of pig you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by Build the pig using ant from the cygwin home. Then it works fine. The command to build pig in the cygwin terminal is **ant clean jar-withouthadoop -Dhadoopversion=23**